# Google cloud print suddenly stopped working -- using same Windows 10 laptop

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, printing, google-cloud-print

After printing successfully many times to my Canon MP600 (classic) printer, suddenly Google Cloud Print gives me an error message every time.

I'm using a Dell XPS laptop (Windows 10 home). I updated to the latest version of Chrome, deleted and then re-added my MP600 both to Windows and to Google Cloud Print, and restarted the computer.

Still won't print! It gives an error message immediately. GCP recognizes the printer just fine.

Thank you!

---

Error message:

> ```
> Print failure 
> Submitted 0 minutes ago by xxxxxxx@gmail.com
> Advanced Details
> Content Type
> application/pdf
> Print Job ID
> e114d421-461e-7018-2a4c-84027b1dbc23
> Printer ID
> ab24d631-991d-1eee-10cc-2ff6705d654e
> Last Updated
> Jan 24, 2016, 7:31:54 PM
> Tags
> ^own  
> print_file    
> dashboard
> ```

---

Here is the information given when you look up the printer:

> ```
> CANON MP600
>
> Owned by me
> Added 14 minutes ago
> Location unavailable
> Printer is online and ready to print
>
> Printer Type
> Classic printer connected via Google Chrome
> Registered with Cloud Print
> Jan 24, 2016, 7:31:13 PM
> Last Updated
> Jan 24, 2016, 7:31:13 PM
> Printer ID
> ab24d631-991d-1eee-10cc-2ff6705d654e
> Google Cloud Print Version
> 1.0
> Supported Content Types
> application/pdf
> Proxy
> 14DA45E5-3024-4619-A2BE-B938FA872983
> Tags
> ^recent   
> ^own  
> ^connector    
> ^can_share    
> ^can_update   
> ^can_delete   
> __cp__chrome_version  48.0.2564.82 m
> __cp__printer-make-and-model  Canon MP600 Printer
> __cp__system_driverinfo   Canon MP600 Printer;2.00.4.13;Canon IJ Printer Driver;2.00.4.13
> __cp__system_name Windows NT
> __cp__system_version  10.0
> __cp__tagshash    f8a8d0ca9787532f448267e55bc80a81
> ```

Comment: Closevoters: this question is perfectly on-topic here, since Google Cloud Print has a component that runs on the local computer.

Comment: Anyone find a solution for this?